# How to make sure a directory is always constructed the same way in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a python script that does a lot of tedious file handling for me.
To make sure nothing can go wrong I wanted to create the file structure I need from scratch everytime.
Wondering if there is an easier way to do this...

```
if os.path.exists(pth_temp_data) == 1:
    shutil.rmtree(pth_temp_data.joinpath("Presets/Factory_Presets/Global_Presets"))
    shutil.rmtree(pth_temp_data.joinpath("Presets/Factory_Presets"))
    shutil.rmtree(pth_temp_data.joinpath("Presets"))
    shutil.rmtree(pth_temp_data)
    os.makedirs(pth_temp_presets)
else:
    os.makedirs(pth_temp_presets)
```

Comment: If you are going to `shutil.rmtree(pth_temp_data)` - i.e., recursively delete the entire folder - anyway, what is the point of deleting subfolders first? If you are going to `os.makedirs(pth_temp_presets)` *whether or not* there was already a `pth_temp_data`, then why not do it *unconditionally, after* the conditional logic?

Comment: in my tests shutil.rmtree can only remove one directory at a time. It might be able to delete all the contents along with a dir but if I try to immediately delete the top layer then I get the error " dir is not empty"

Comment: @observantsound if your code is placed outside the `pth_temp_data ` dir then `shutil.rmtree(pth_temp_data)` will delete the directory, it doesn't matter if there are files or folder in the directory, all will be deleted

Comment: @prashantMaurya not according to what I'm seeing. shutil.rmtree(pth_temp_data) results in error: "Directory is not empty"